# Auto-Responder with Attachment in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I would like to setup an auto-responder in Gmail that includes an attachment. I can setup the auto-responder without issue but how do I add an attachment to an auto-responder in Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this can be done via Gmail.

I can suggest writing a simple application that connects to your server, checks new emails, and sends new email.

I am sure there are plenty of similar free tools available online.

Comment: I have considered this but wanted to check the simple route if available. I will now look this route. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Gmail [automatic vacation response](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=25922) feature doesn't seem to allow attachments. However, you can include a link to the attachment in the response. You can upload the file to a Google Docs account, and [share the file to anyone with the link](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180199&topic=1360909&ctx=topic). Or you could upload the file to some other file sharing service.

Comment: I have thought of that unfortunately I need it sent as an attachment not a link.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at uploading your attachment to a file hosting site e.g. mediafire. The problem I have found with this however is that the autoresponder message limits you to how many words you can put in the message which for me turned out to be a challenge as my autoresponse requires a lot of instructions!

Comment: Asker has [already indicated it must be an attachment, not a link](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24899/auto-responder-with-attachment-in-gmail/24900#comment19047_24901).